# Polynomials maps

Tags: polynomials

Looking at past exam papers I have seen several question of this style but don't know how to answer it. Any help in the methods need to be uses to calculate would be a great help

Consider  $\phi: \mathbb{A}^1_k \rightarrow \mathbb{A}^2_k$ defined  by $\phi(t)=(t^2-1,t^3+3) $.

a) Describe the induced map $\phi^* \colon  k[x,y] \rightarrow k[t]$ and compute $\phi^*(x^2-y^2)$.

b) Describe the ideal $J_\phi \subset  k[x,y,t] $ and explain how to use $J_\phi$ to compute the kernel of $\phi^*$

c) Give a generating set for the Kernel of $\phi^*$

d) Is the point $(1,-1)$ in the Zariski closure of the image of $\phi$?

.

Im quite sure $J_\phi=(x-(t^2-1),y-(t^3+3))$.

Answer (score 1):

a) is simple. As $\phi$ simply says "put $t^2-1$ into $x$ and $t^3+3$ into $y$", this is what we do for polynomials with $\phi^*$. Thus $\phi^*(f)=f(t^2-1,t^3+3)$, especially $\phi^*(x^2-y^2)=(t^2-1)^2-(t^3+3)^2=-t^6+t^4-6t^3-2t^2+8$.

c) Here is *one* element of the kernel: $f(x,y)=x^3-y^2+3x^2+6y+3x+8$, obtained by eliminating coefficients from $t^6$ downwards.

d) Since $f(1,-1)=-8\ne0$ (assuming characteristic $\ne2$) with the $f$ from part c, the point $(1,-1)$ is not in the closure. (In characteristic $2$, we have in fact $\phi(1,1)=(1,-1)$, i.e. the opint *is* in the image and even more so in the closure)

Comment: Im not sure how you worked out part c) what do I have to do to eliminate coefficients?